# How can I hide a listing from Airbnb's result list?

Tags: airbnb

When searching for a place on  Airbnb, I sometimes would like to hide a listing from Airbnb's result list so that I don't have to screen it anymore (as in a few minutes/hours I might have forgotten I'm not interested in them).

How can I hide a listing from Airbnb's result list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airbnb doesn't offer that option (instead the offer filtering for places that have shampoo and hangers; how useful!).

The closest I've seen to "hiding" a listing was to see listing on the map view, and click on them from the map view. Those become grey. If you like a listing, heart it, and that will show on the map.